# Fourier transform - LTSpice

Tags: ltspice, fourier, education

Is it possible to get the Fourier transform in LTSpice? For example I'd like to plot the Fourier transform of the following signal:

$$s(t)=A \space sin(2\pi f_0t)$$

[image]

Can you attached a LTSpice example file please?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Right click on the waveform window and choose `View>FFT`. It is assumd you know what you're doing and know how to set up your signal period & co. Also, you wil only see the shifted (to the right) version, but that shouldn't matter too much.

Comment: Hi @aconcerncitizen, I did it, but the result is an horrible wave.

Comment: Then you most probably didn't match the number of periods, it has to be an exact number. Or your signal is too distorted, for example it may have a decaying component and you need to let it simulate until it reaches a reasonable steady state. Could you post a screenshot of the waveform? Or, if it's not too complicated/secret/etc, of the schematic?

Comment: Consider this example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRGjg.png . If the periods don't match, you'll get garbage, or you'll have to use a window of some sorts, here Kaiser (`beta=7`).

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen This is the file http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=03158981807616873657. The left blu curve in your image is good.

Comment: I'm not sure what goes wrong for you. Simply choosing `View>FFT`, no other settings, reveals a bin of ~10.97dB@1Hz, with rather high noise floor and minor harmonics (because LTspice, by default, uses waveform compression). If you impose a tighter timestep (say `1ms`, or so), you'll get better noise floor, and if you also add `.opt plotwinsize=0` it will disable waveform compression and you'll get hundreds of dB noise floor. If you're expecting to see a textbook picture, you won't. LTspice shows what a spectrum analyser would show (or similar).

Comment: Just a thought: if you right-click the Y axis and choose `linear`, you'll get a clearer picture.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen I tried to plot FFT with and without the imposition of Maximum Timestep, but the two waveforms are equal. What would have to change?

Comment: ...moreover it is strange that the amplitude of the peak is 3.5V. The amplitude of sin is 5, thus I expected a coefficient with 5/2=2.5 amplitude because the Fourier's coefficient for k=1 is $$X_{k=1}=-\frac{j \space sin's \space amplitude}{2}$$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61911/discussion-between-a-concerned-citizen-and-gennaro-arguzzi).

Comment: Hello @aconcernedcitizen, I wrote in the chat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is beyond the capablities of circuit simulators. The simulators handle only finite length signal bursts. You will not get the same spectrum, because the signal in your example is the theoretical sinewave which has never started and will never stop. It has existed unchanged from t = -eternity and will go on to t = +eternity. It has infinite energy, so it occurs as Dirac's impulses in the Fourier transform.

Simulators calculate the discrete fourier transform. It's said FFT due the used high-speed calculation algorithm. It shows the signal as it were combined from sinewaves which have frequencies 0, 1/T, 2/T, 3/T...Fsample/2 where T is the simulation period and Fsample is the used sample rate.

If your sample rate in the simulation happens to be an integral part of the cycle length of the sinewave and the simulation time period happens to be an integral multiple of the cycle length and no automatic smooth windowing spoils the start and end, then you get something that resembles your theoretical spectrum. It will not be strictly 2 spikes. The numeric rounding errors occur as a noise floor (=extra frequency components) in the spectrum. The energy of the spectrum only will be not infite, but the total energy of the sinewave in the simulation period.

Unfortunately I have not LTspice and do not know, how to order the right Fourier transform mode (=rectangular windowing, show positive and negative frequencies and the phase angles).

Answer (score 1):

I've never tried it myself, but from the LTspice Help.

.FOUR -- Compute a Fourier Component after a .TRAN Analysis
Syntax: .four  [Nharmonics] [Nperiods]  [ ...]

Example: .four 1kHz V(out)

This command is performed after a transient analysis. It's supplied in order to be compatible with legacy SPICE simulators. The output from this command is printed in the .log file. Use the menu item "View=>Spice Error Log" to see the output. For most purposes, the FFT capability built into the waveform viewer is more useful.

If the integer Nharmonics is present, then the analysis includes that number of harmonics. The number of harmonics defaults to 9 if not specified.

The Fourier analysis is performed over the period from the final time, Tend, to one period before Tend unless an integer Nperiods is given after Nharmonics. If Nperiods is given as -1, the Fourier analysis is performed over the entire simulation data range.

Comment: OP wants to see a visual representation, not a table of characters.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that LTspice simulate, thus it can not output the real analytic Fourier transform. But you can get a close approximation of it by looking at the FFT output of an ideal source. Also the resulting graph shows only the real half of the Fourier transform

As you can see below for the sine function: $$ s(t)= 1 \cdot sin(2\pi \cdot 1\cdot10^3 \cdot t)$$
Which has the net name sine_out on my simulation.

[image]